# ASP dotnet core webApp: SignalR websocket onclose() called immediately after request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm just starting with SignalR in a asp dotnet core web app and try to get a basic understanding.

I have worked through the [getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) example from Microsoft with an empty project and it works well. Then I tried to integrate the same tutorial in an existing web app. But there, I can only send one request to the server. After receiving the response, the page content is updated as expected. But then the error handler on `connection.invoke(...).catch(...)` is immediately invoked with the information: `Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed`

The call stack pointed me to the `webSocket.onclose` function in `signalr.js` But I cannot see why the corresponding event is raised.

The complete debug information from server and client after setting SignalR.js LogLevel to `Trace` is:

```
[2020-12-17T16:03:21.698Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 76.
[2020-12-17T16:03:21.701Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of length 60.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/chathub'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 6917.5314ms 101 
[2020-12-17T16:03:21.709Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) socket closed.
[2020-12-17T16:03:21.709Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Connected.
[2020-12-17T16:03:21.710Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
[2020-12-17T16:03:21.710Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(undefined) called while in state Connected.
Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed.
```

I can thereafter reconnect and the connection works again for one request. But this cannot be a solution.

I have overriden `OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)` on the server and put a Breakpoint to it. The `exception` parameter is null, but `this.Context.ConnectionAborted.IsCancellationRequested` is `true`.
The call to `OnDisconnectedAsync(...)` happens after the the JS client function for the result has been executed successfully without any issues.

Since it works in a clean new project, I'm sure it is related to something in my existing web app. But I have absolutely no clue what it might be.
I've already commented out everything else in `Startup.cs` and excluded every other JS scripts from the page for testing to avoid any side effects. I should now have essentially the same setup as in the example. But the behaviour doesn't change.

I don't expect a concrete solution since this might be a very specific issue. But it would already help if anyone has an idea where I should start looking for the Problem.

**Edit:**
After investigating this further and debugging `signalr.js` I discovered that `webSocket.onclose(event)` is called after the `processIncomingData(...)` function has finished without an error. The event code is 1000 which according to [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent) means `Normal Closure`. But I still cannot find who initiates the close call...

Comment: Hi @Buchter which hub method do you invoke, can you show us it?

Comment: I call the `SendMessage` Methode from `ChatHub` just like in the MS example. And the result then is evaluated in the `ReceiveMessage` handler in my JavaScript. Thereafter the disconnection happens.

Comment: @Lightbringer, have you resolved that problem? I have the same issue. It looks like SignalR disconnects (server side) immediately after any call

Comment: @adam.bielasty: Not really. During that period of time I was in the transition from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET5 and I later guessed that there was an issue with mismatching packages. After it worked in a new .NET 5 Project, I reseted my workspace and did the update to .NET 5 for the existing project. Thereafter it worked as expected. Might well be related to what you offered as an answer below. Maybe some problem with newer Newtonsoft.Json package together with .NET Core 3.1. But I have no proof.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the identical issue.

It looks like after going to .net core 3.1 angular app started disconnecting from hub after each signalr call with the message:

```
HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Connected
```

The signalr lib was not giving any meaningful message. I managed to track the call stack and find out that it comes from server side disconnections. The

```
OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
```

was giving also no information (the exception was null)

The solution was to change **Startup.cs** to:

```
            services.AddSignalR(configure =>
            {
                configure.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            })
            //...
            .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(); // <--------- that's the important change
```

So, after adding:
**.AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()** from **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson**
all started working as expected.

Comment: re: the exception passed through to `OnDisconnectedAsync` being null, follow that bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26701